In OpenSearch getting error "Missing required property 'PutComponentTemplateRequest.template'" while creating using PutComponentTemplateRequest
I am getting Missing required property 'PutComponentTemplateRequest.template' while creating  only index settings template using PutComponentTemplateRequest class. I am using opensearch-java client and version 2.13.0. Please find the below code snippet:
 PutComponentTemplateRequest putComponentTemplateRequest = PutComponentTemplateRequest.of(
                c -> c.name(indexSettingsComponentTemplate)
                    .settings(
                        s -> s.numberOfShards("2")
                            .numberOfReplicas("1")
                            .indexing(
                                i -> i.slowlog(
                                    sl -> sl.level("info")
                                        .reformat(true)
                                        .threshold(th -> th.index(ith -> ith.warn(Time.of(t -> t.time("2s")))))
                                )
                            )
                            .search(
                                se -> se.slowlog(sl -> sl.level("info").threshold(th -> th.query(q -> q.warn(Time.of(t -> t.time("2s"))))))
                            )
                    )
            ); 

